# Java and XML: How to get list of included files

Tags: java, xml, xinclude, xml-entities

I have problem with by Xinclude or as an entity included files. I need to know, which files have been included by parser. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE docBookChapter [
    <!ENTITY externalFile SYSTEM "entityIncluded.xml">
]>
<chapter xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <title>Third chapter</title>
    <xi:include href="xIncluded.xml"/>
    <chapter>
        &externalFile;</chapter>
</chapter>
```

The parser creates DOM successfully, but how to get names of files included? The element `xi:include` is already replaced with content of file.

Comment: How did you parse the xml?  Are you using standard Java DOM parsing?

Comment: Yes, I do. I create a `DocumentBuilderFactory` instance and then a document builder instance. The document builder uses Xerces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend [`DefaultHandler`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html) and `@Overwrite` the `resolveEntity` method. Your implementation will simply print or log the publicId/systemId and return `null`, so the `SAXParser` will use the default behaviour to resolve the entities.

Pass your `DefaultHandler` subclass with the `SAXParser` constructor.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. For all included files (either x-included or included as an entity) the method obtains absolute path of a file merged as the `systemId` parameter.